# Word 365 "Save as pdf file" window freezes up for no reason

Tags: pdf, bug, microsoft-word-365

I am trying to save word document as a pdf file using Microsoft Print to PDF

[image]

When the "Save as PDF" dialog box opens, it sort of freezes up. Clicks/keyboard keypresses do not seem to register, except Esc key which just immediately closes the "save as" dialog. If I type out something on the keyboard then press Esc, in the split second before the "Save as" dialog disappears, I can see whatever I typed out before pressing Esc in the dialog box's "filename" textbox. This happens too fast for me to take a screenshot. Sometimes, if I fiddle around with random keys on the keyboard, the "Save as" dialog box becomes responsive again and then it starts working normally.

This seems to be a bug in Word 365 (along with other small bugs I have encountered). This one is especially annoying because I frequently need to convert docx files to pdf. Is there any workaround to this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Print" or you can save it as PDF:

[image]